# How to get the WebProxy used by existing instance of an HttpHandler?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

How do I write out the **address** of the WebProxy, that is used by my HttpHandler, when I only have access to that Handler and Client?

```
var CookieBox = new CookieContainer();
var Handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = CookieBox, UseProxy = true, Proxy = GetProxy() };
var Client = new HttpClient(Handler) { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(loop * 10) };
```

Result like 84.100.101.102:10045 is what I need.`Handler.Proxy.GetProxy()` seems not to be it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out.

The `IWebProxy Handler.Proxy` is a `WebProxy` instance which does expose the `Address` member. Just cast it.

```
var tempProxy = (WebProxy)Handler.Proxy;
Console.WriteLine(tempProxy.Address);
```